# Specflow error using TestDriven.Net - Couldn't Find Type

Tags: testdriven.net, specflow

I'm trying out Specflow for the first time, and have created a VS2010 project with a reference to TechTalk.SpecFlow, as well as nunit.framework.  I've added a sample Feature file:

```
Feature: Addition
    In order to avoid silly mistakes
    As a math idiot
    I want to be told the sum of two numbers

@mytag
Scenario: Add two numbers
    Given I have entered 50 into the calculator
    And I have entered 70 into the calculator
    When I press add
    Then the result should be 120 on the screen
```

When I execuyte the test (using TestDriven.Net), I get the following error:

```
Test 'T:SpecFlowFeature1' failed: Couldn't find type with name 'SpecFlowFeature1'
System.Exception: Couldn't find type with name 'SpecFlowFeature1'
at MutantDesign.Xml.Documentation.MemberInfoUtilities.FindMemberInfo(Assembly assembly, String cref)
at TestDriven.TestRunner.AdaptorTestRunner.Run(ITestListener testListener, ITraceListener traceListener, String assemblyPath, String testPath)
at TestDriven.TestRunner.ThreadTestRunner.Runner.Run()
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Answer (score 5):

Actually traced this down to how I was running the test.  Right clicking the "*.feature" file (or anywhere within that file) and selecting "Run Tests" resulted in the error.  Right clicking the underlying "*.feature.cs" file and selecting "Run Tests" executed correctly.  Looks like TestDriven.Net wasn't able to "understand" the "*.feature" file.

Comment: yes, unfortunately the unit test runners are not prepared for tests that are generated from another file. :-(

Comment: Had the same issue with an F# (xunit) test. Run tests from within the code file resulted in a similar error. Run tests on the library gave me the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I typically start "Couldn't find type..." errors in my references folder and make sure that the library that I'm referencing is being referenced correctly and that the version that's being referenced isn't outdated.

Also, make sure that your SpecFlowFeature1 class isn't mistakenly declared as private.  Visual Studio creates new classes (by default) as private and if you don't specify a class as public, it will remain private and not "visible" to outside projects.